# Can I force a windows 10/11 program to be unresponsive?

Tags: windows, exe

Is there anyway to set a program to be unresponsive in windows?

I have python code that starts a program. But when the program becomes unresponsive i want to do some specific clean up task.

But how do I test it. Because currently it is random.
Is there a way to either make a small program that I can force to be unresponsive?

Or force a running program to be unresponsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "unresponsive" program is typically a GUI application that's blocked on it's main (UI) thread such that it hasn't pumped messages in a long time. That is, the UI feels "frozen" when you try to interact with it and/or the window doesn't seem to repaint itself as it should.

You can easily simulate this by creating a Windows Forms app in C#  or Win32 GUI app in C++ using the default project templates in Visual Studio. Or basically any UI framework like Qt for that matter.  Then introduce a very long sleep statement (several minutes) in response to a button click.

I don't think the "unresponsive" attribute applies to services, console applications, or background tasks.

Comment: Ahh ofcourse. Makes sense I will take that route.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alt + Tab keyboard shortcut to bring your unresponsive program to the front, and then press Alt + F4 keys at the same time to force the program to quit.

Comment: I am not asking how to close it. I want to force a program to be unresponsive. So i can detect it and do something when it happens.

I is just a hard case to test. Because it does not become unresponsive everytime.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).